# Microsoft 365 keeps asking for "Approve Sign-in request" during login

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication, microsoft365

I have deleted the MFA device from my Microsoft 365 account using this link https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info.

When I perform an SSO login for one of the applications it asks for an MFA **Approve Sign-in request** after I enter my credentials.

Note: SSO is configured through SAML. We are using AWS Cognito as Service Provider and Azure AD as an Identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

**I have followed the below steps to disable MFA during Login:**

> Note: If you delete the mobile device from [Signin](https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info) portal, **MFA** will enforce to register the device again. inorder to disable the MFA on user account.
> Kindly disable MFA on **M365** portal. see the  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/101179/how-to-disable-the-two-factor-authentication-from) by **Emily Du-MSFT**

I have enabled **Multi-Factor Authentication** to office 365 users.

[image]

Select the checkbox for the same user for enforce MFA, Under **Quick Steps**, Select **Enforce**.

[image]

If tried to login to office 365 with same user account, MFA will enforce to register, like below.
[image]

If I login to [mysignin](https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info) portal, my mobile device is registered successfully.

[image]

Once delete the device from Sign_in portal, MFA will enforce automatically to register the device again.

[image]

Inorder to disable the MFA on user account. disable **MFA** in **Office 365 Portal**.

[image]

Comment: Under Azure, I have 2 org. One is Home and another org. is created to store guest/external users who can access our application through SSO.  To access apps that are under Home Org. I am receiving notifications on Auth app but when I try to access my SSO-enabled app I am not receiving notifications on Auth app. But UI keeps displaying Approve Sign-in request and that is creating a blocker for me.

Comment: if you want to disable the MFA on Auth App, check the users in Applications and disable MFA on M365 Portal.

Comment: I want users to get a notification on the Authenticator app so they can approve the Sign-in request which is currently not happening.

Comment: if you need notification on Authenticator App, Ask user to register the device in MFA Portal and select the sign in method.

Comment: The user did that. He set up the MFA device. He receives notifications only for apps under the Home organization. But he is not receiving notifications while trying to access the SSO-enabled app which is under the new org. created. But UI shows Approve Sign-in request page.

Comment: is SSO enabled app also configured in Home Organization or different organization?

Comment: Under different org.

Comment: if different org, check the MFA enable status in same org and ask user to register the device in same org email id.